# I am trying to bring back a row based on the minimum date, but not bring back the date field

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
select customer_id, street_address, city, state, zip  
from customer  where min(date);
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: There must be customer id field in the table ?

Comment: Welcome! In order to make your question answerable, please be sure to include all relevant details including your table structure, the database system in question (Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL, DB2, HANA, HSQL, etc).  The more detail you provide, the more quickly your question will be answered.  Also search SO carefully for examples where your question may have already been answered.

Comment: Can you share the schema of your table? Do you have an id column?

Comment: I am using Oracle and yes there is a customer_id field. so the correct select statement would be: customer_id, select street_address, city, state, zip from customer where min(date);

Comment: lol ok then you need this: select customer_id,street_address, city, state, zip from customer a
    inner join (select customer_id, min(date) as min_date from customer group by customer_id) b
    on a.customer_id=b.customer_id and a.date=b.min_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if Teradata:

```
select customer_id, street_address, city, state, zip from customer 
qualify row_number() over(partition customer_id order by date)=1
```

Other options:

```
select customer_id,street_address, city, state, zip from customer a
inner join (select customer_id, min(date) as min_date from customer group by customer_id) b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id and a.date=b.min_date
```

Comment: I'm sorry i should have been more descriptive. The "other options" brings back the data that I want but only one row. I have multiple entries on each customer and want to bring back 1 row for each customer with the earliest date. How would you change it to bring back all. Thank you!

Comment: aha :) I wasn't clear on that - but are you using Teradata or no?

Comment: No, not using teradata.

Comment: sorry was doing all this in a rush...still made n error - I keep joining on customer but there's no customer field - I assume each customer is identified through street address, city, etc., so you have to join on those fields in the last line - SORRYYY

Comment: each customer has a customer_id field for the primary key

Comment: I just changed the original post to reflect the customer_id_field.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are trying this in T-SQL. you can try using CTE (common table expression)

Example:

```
select 'a123' street_address, 'as' city,'ap' state, 123456 zip, cast(getdate()-10 as date) [day] into #temp
insert into #temp values('b12','ad','aw',345478,cast(getdate()-1 as date))
insert into #temp values('c243','a2','a3',3458,cast(getdate()-12 as date))
insert into #temp values('e3d','a2','af',8324,cast(getdate()-13 as date))
insert into #temp values('f46','a3','ag',337,cast(getdate()-13 as date))
insert into #temp values('g23','a4','ah',0374,cast(getdate()-1 as date))
insert into #temp values('h12','af','aj',946,cast(getdate()-17 as date))
insert into #temp values('634','ad','a8',345,cast(getdate()-17 as date))

select * from #temp

--Query to return min valued row
;with q as (select min(day) minday from #temp)
select street_address, city, state, zip from #temp t cross apply q where t.day=q.minday
```

Blog to read for CTE:
       https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Answer (score 0):

On of the simplest solutions that will work in every rdbms is:

```
select customer_id, street_address, city, state, zip 
from customer 
where date in (select min(date) from customer)
;
```